# Euler Bernouli Beam theory and its application to vibration of beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vibration

Could anyone please explain what is exactly Euler Bernoulli Beam Theory and why and how its applied in Vibration of Cantilever Beam frequencies and mode shapes . Please use simple differential rather than comples

Comment: What books have you come across so we don't waste our time duplicating things where you turn around and say "I have read that already"...